# Why are the functions $H_t$ in a homotopy continuous for all $0 \le t \le 1$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

If $f,g: X \to Y$ are two continuous functions, the definition of a homotopy between them that is a continuous function $H:I \times X \to Y$ where $H(0,x) = f(x)$ and $H(1,x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

In *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* it then states that the functions $H_t:X \to Y$ defined by $H_t(x) = H(t,x)$ are a family of continuous functions. I'm confused about how to deduce that the functions $H_t$ are continuous given that $H$ is continuous.

I thought about looking at the universal property of product spaces but this gives a statement about continuous maps into $I \times X$ as opposed to continuous maps out of $I \times X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a specific $t$, Try showing that the function $f:X \to I \times X$, defined by $f(x) = (t,x)$ is continuous. Then deduce that $H_t$ is continuous, using composition of functions.